# How can I change child component background color

Tags: javascript, react-native

I implement two simple react component like this:

Users Component (Parent):

```
export default class Users extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            users:[
                {id:1,name:'name1'},
                {id:2,name:'name2'},
                {id:3,name:'name3'},
                {id:4,name:'name4'}
            ]
        }
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Users</Text>
                {this.state.data.map((user) => {
                    return <Card user={user}/>
                })}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Card Component (Child):

```
class Card extends React.Component {

render(){
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.props.user.name}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

}
```

I want changing the background color of card when tap on,

And I try change Card component to this:

```
class Card extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            BGClass: 'unselectedCard'
        }
    }

    select() {

        this.setState({BGClass: 'selectedCard'})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                this.select()
            }}>
                <View  style={styles[this.state.BGClass]}>
                    <Text>Card</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
}
```

With this change, when I tap on Card, Card background is change but my problem is when new Card is changed to selected background color, another card not return to unselected background color,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to ES6 class methods which are not bound to the class instance by default (see [issue 9851](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9851))

Change:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
    this.select()
}}>
```

To:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.select.bind(this)}>
```

Alternatively (and better approach), would be to add this line in the constructor:

```
this.select = this.select.bind(this)
```

## EDIT

```
export default class Users extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            users:[
                {id:1,name:'name1'},
                {id:2,name:'name2'},
                {id:3,name:'name3'},
                {id:4,name:'name4'}
            ],
            selectedUserId: null,
        }
    }

    select(userId) {
        this.setState({selectedUserId: userId})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Users</Text>
                {this.state.data.map((user) => {
                    return <Card user={user} isSelected={user.id === this.state.selectedUserId} onSelect={this.select.bind(this)}/>
                })}
            </View>
        )
    }
}

class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                this.props.onSelect(this.props.user.id)
            }}>
                <View  style={!this.props.isSelected && styles['unselectedCard']}>
                    <Text>Card</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: this.select() work but how can I change another <Card/> background to unselected style

Comment: You have to defined the select method in the parent component and pass it as a prop to `Card` component

Comment: There are still many problems with this code (efficiency, readability, linting, ...)

Comment: this code is simple for more understanding,may be give me a simple code that how can I do it ?

Comment: thanks alot for this sample code , but  this.props.isSelected always is false

Comment: I change selectedUserId  to this.state.selectedUserId and it work , thanks for useful response